# 2 View Controllers, One with List of Items - Passing to First VC

Tags: iphone, core-data, viewcontroller

I have a tab bar controller interface with the main concept of creating an ID, adding a name via textfield and then adding multiple user selected properties via a push segue to a view controller.

I have resolved the main add ID view controller and the push segue to add a single property from the detail view controller, but now I would like to modify the scenario...

1. On the detail view controller I have a list of Procedures and the user can select one that is passed back to the main view...how can I set it up as a "checkbox" or multiple selection method and have all of the procedure choices passed back to the main view instead of just one?
2. I am using core data as my storage model and relationships between the main entity "MedRec" and the other entities that compose the data of MedRec- "Procedure", "Level", "Date", etc.

   ```
   #import "MedRecTVC.h"

   #import "MedRec.h"

   @implementation MedRecTVC

   @synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
   @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
   @synthesize selectedMedRec;

   -(void)setupFetchedResultsController

   {
   // 1 - Decide what Entity you want

   NSString *entityName = @"MedRec"; //Put your entity name here
   NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

   // 2 - Request the Entity

   NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

   // 3 - Filter it if you want

   //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Level.name = Blah"];

   // 4 - Sort it if you want

   request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor            sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

   // 5 - Fetch it

   self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

   [self performFetch];

   }

   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self setupFetchedResultsController];
   }


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MedRec Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   //configure the cell

   //decide the order of table cell text and detail text

   MedRec *medrec = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", medrec.number];
   cell.textLabel.text = number;
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = medrec.inLevel.level1;

   return cell;
   }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

   [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

   // Delete the role object that was swiped
   MedRec *medrecToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", medrecToDelete.number);
   [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:medrecToDelete];
   [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

   // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
   [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   [self performFetch];

   [self.tableView endUpdates];
   }
   }

   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add MedRec Segue"])
   {
   NSLog(@"Setting MedRecTVC as a delegate of AddMedRecTVC");

   AddMedRecTVC *addMedRecTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
   addMedRecTVC.delegate = self;
   addMedRecTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
   }

   else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MedRec Detail Segue"])
   {
   NSLog(@"Setting MEdRecTVC as a delegate of MedRecDetailTVC");
   MedRecDetailTVC *medrecDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
   medrecDetailTVC.delegate = self;
   medrecDetailTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   self.selectedMedRec = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSLog(@"Passing selected medrec (%@) to MedRecDetailTVC", self.selectedMedRec.number);
   medrecDetailTVC.medrec = self.selectedMedRec;
   }

   else {
   NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
   }

   }


   - (void)theSaveButtonOnTheAddMedRecTVCWasTapped:(MedRecDetailTVC *)controller
   {
   //refresh the table
   //close delegated view
   [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   }

   - (void)theSaveButtonOnTheMedRecDetailTVCWasTapped:(MedRecDetailTVC *)controller
   {
   [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }



   @end
   ```